# Wordpress # to create product link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I'm working on redoing a clients website using wordpress. Their previous developer who wrote the website from scratch, made a products sku/product id with a hash/pound sign '#' in front of the sku/product id number in the text editting of the product in the admin section would create a link to the existing product. I was wondering what language and what the code might look like so I could successfully do essentially the same thing. I've already created in WooCommerce a uniform shortlink to all products using the SKU/Product ID.

Ex: **#7512D** would create a link as following;

```
<a href="bioquip.com/search/dispproduct.asp?pid=7512D">7512D</a>
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions here: why do you wonder what language to use? You're already settled on WordPress, by the sounds of it, which uses PHP, as I'm sure you're aware. The code snipped you share, though has an `asp` extension in the URL. Not sure what to make of that!

Comment: The website is a very old website that we are finally updating. We decided to go with Wordpress for easier customizing and functionality.

Comment: Got it - and you're looking to duplicate the old functionality within wordpress?

Comment: Yes that is correct. There are tons of our descriptions of products that used this old functionality and instead of going through everyone and having to code the links (which change often) this avoids having to stay on top of all our products and avoiding broken links.

Comment: Do you mind giving this question a up on the question being useful? I'm trying to get enough reputation points to start contributing more to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done as a plugin to keep it theme independent and it simply needs to filter the "content" of the post (or page). Here's a working example using WooCommerce. It uses the same design as you mentioned in your post (#XXXXXX), but I recommend you find something other than the "#" to use as the beginning of the match. This will match all of the HTML encoded characters that are in the `&#8217;` format. While the SKU lookup makes sure you won't have an errant match, it means that there will be a lot more queries than there need to be.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Replace SKU with Link
Description: Plugin to replace a formatted SKU (#XXXXXX) with the link to that product
Version: 1.0
*/

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No direct access!' );

class SkuReplace {

    /*
    * On __construct, we will initialize the filter for the content
    */
    function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'replace_sku_with_link' ) );
    }

    /**
    * The filter hook get processed here
    *
    * @return string the filtered content
    */
    function replace_sku_with_link( $content )
    {

        // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single post page.
        if ( ( is_single() || is_page() ) && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() )
        {
            // Use the callback to check to see if this product exists in the DB
            $content = preg_replace_callback(
                '/\#[^\s\<]*/',
                array( $this, 'get_product_url' ),
                $content
            );
        }

        return $content;
    }

    /**
    * The match is checked against the product entries to verify that it exists
    * If it does, it will create the hyperlink and return it, else, it returns
    * the original string so as not to break the content
    *
    * @return string URL or original string
    */
    function get_product_url( $in )
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $sku = ltrim( rtrim( $in[0], " \t\r\n" ), '#');

        $product_id = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1",
                $sku
            )
        );

        if( $product_id )
        {
            $product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

            $url = get_permalink( $product_id ) ;

            return '<a href="'. $url .'">'. $product->get_name() .'</a>';
        }

        return $in[0];
    }

} // end class

$plugin_name = new SkuReplace();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I found that it's broken the single product pages. Would another symbol like '@' be better than '#'? If so would I replace the '#' where ever it appears in the php above?

Comment: If it is breaking the pages, then it is likely conflicting with some other plugin. You can try turning off other plugins until you see it working to see what the conflict is. You may need to adjust the timing of the `add_filter()` call.

Comment: I've deactivated all the plugins and if there is a # in the description text to create the link all the description will not load and the admin wp banner is blank.