# wordpress auto sku link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a client's new website using WordPress. Their previous website built from scratch, connected a products product id with a '#' in front of the product id number in the admin section would create a link to the existing page of another product. I was wondering how I might successfully do essentially the same thing in Wordpress. **Ex:** #1012A would create a link as following;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recommended previously that it be done as PHP, as a plugin to keeping it independent from the theme. [Check out my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293020/wordpress-to-create-product-link/44313495#44313495)